# Rally grid with custom column renderer sort

Tags: sorting, rally

**Background**

When I try to sort by a column that I have used a custom renderer for, nothing happens - it changes the sort from ASC to DESC and back and forth but the order of the data never changes.  I am assuming this is because there is not definition of how to sort the data that I manipulated with a custom renderer, but I cannot seem to find a way to add a sorter or sorting function to the column.

**Goal**

I am making a grid that I want to sort by the Parent column. I want to sort it such that the parent appears just above any of its children (the parent being a Rollup and the children being Features).

**Idea**

For features, put the name of the Parent in the parent column.  For Rollups, put the Name of itself in the parent column and add a class to it that sets

```
display: none;
```

Then, you can easily sort it out and have parents appearing just above children

**Code**

```
{
    text: 'Parent',
    dataIndex: 'Parent',
    renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        var ret = record.raw.Parent;
        if (ret) {
            return ret.Name;
        } else {
            meta.tdCls = 'invisible';
            return record.data.Name;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I would suggest putting `record.get('Parent')` instead of using `record.raw.Parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rallygrid config, make sure you set the property of remoteSort, which is by default true, to false.  Then, here is the config for the column:

```
            {dataIndex: 'Parent', name: 'Parent', 
                doSort: function(state) {
                    var ds = this.up('grid').getStore();
                    var field = this.getSortParam();
                    console.log('field',field);
                    ds.sort({
                        property: field,
                        direction: state,
                        sorterFn: function(v1, v2){
                            console.log('v1',v1);
                            console.log('v2',v2);
                            if (v1.raw.Parent) {
                                v1 = v1.raw.Parent.Name;
                            } else {
                                v1 = v1.data.Name;
                            }

                            if (v2.raw.Parent) {
                                v2 = v2.raw.Parent.Name;
                            } else {
                                v2 = v2.data.Name;
                            }

                            return v1.localeCompare(v2);
                        }
                    });
                },
                renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                    var ret = record.raw.Parent;
                    if (ret) {
                        return ret.Name;
                    } else {
                        meta.tdCls = 'invisible';
                        return record.data.Name;
                    }
                }
            },
```