# SDK2: sorting custom column in a rally grid

Tags: rally

I have a rally grid that shows defects.  I want do add a column that shows the number of days a defect has been open.

I know can do that by adding a custom renderer in the column configs, but I would also like to sort on this column.  Unfortunately, the renderer does not change the sorting of the column.

I think I might be able to use the convert() function on the store instead to create a new virtual column (in this case openAgeDays), but I'm not sure how to do this from the constructor--I presume I make some changes to storeConfig?

Does anyone have an example of how to use a convert function (assuming that this is the right way to do it) to add a new virtual, sortable column to a rally grid?

```
            this.grid = this.add({
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                model: model,
                disableColumnMenus: false,
                storeConfig: [...]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rally grid with custom column renderer sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755746/rally-grid-with-custom-column-renderer-sort)

Answer (score 1):

As is the answer in the duplicate, you can add a doSort to the column:

```
       {dataIndex: 'Parent', name: 'Parent', 
            doSort: function(state) {
                var ds = this.up('grid').getStore();
                var field = this.getSortParam();
                console.log('field',field);
                ds.sort({
                    property: field,
                    direction: state,
                    sorterFn: function(v1, v2){
                        console.log('v1',v1);
                        console.log('v2',v2);
                        if (v1.raw.Parent) {
                            v1 = v1.raw.Parent.Name;
                        } else {
                            v1 = v1.data.Name;
                        }

                        if (v2.raw.Parent) {
                            v2 = v2.raw.Parent.Name;
                        } else {
                            v2 = v2.data.Name;
                        }

                        return v1.localeCompare(v2);
                    }
                });
            },
            renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                var ret = record.raw.Parent;
                if (ret) {
                    return ret.Name;
                } else {
                    meta.tdCls = 'invisible';
                    return record.data.Name;
                }
            }
        },
```