# Rally JS SDK refresh listener

Tags: sorting, extjs, rally

In case of a `WSJF` App, the app is not sorting columns correctly, it completely ignores the 0's and only sorts the positive non-zero numbers on clicking the column name. So I am trying to write my own sort using the `"refresh"` listener. My question is, **how can the refresh listener know which column was clicked that triggered the listener?**

The refresh listener is as follows:

```
refresh: function(this,eOpts){
  //I need to check which column was clicked, (both this and eOpts) are returning objects but none has values that I can use.
}
```

Comment: This is solved, for more information, refer to [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755746/rally-grid-with-custom-column-renderer-sort